# jQuery mouseover not working in MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Earlier today I asked a question and got a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493912/jquery-pause-delay-timer-on-mouseover/12494127#comment16814309_12494127). However when I added the code to my MVC3 project the jQuery `mouseover` event never gets fired. The jsFiddle in the previous question ([here](http://jsfiddle.net/vypTA/7/)) works fine, but not when I add the code into my script file.

Therefore I decided to modify my `_Layout` file with a much simpler test and that also fails to work with the `mouseover` event. Below is my simple test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.23.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>   
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>   
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {   
            $("#testtest").mouseover(function () {
                $("#testtest").text("OVER");
            }).mouseout(function () {
                $("#testtest").text("OUT");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <header>
            //SNIP
        </header>
        <section id="main">
            <div>

            </div>
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
        <footer>
            //SNIP
        </footer>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both; height: 50px"></div>
    <div id="#testtest" style="background-color: Red; height: 100px; width: 400px; display: block">
        NOTHING
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

I have also tried the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events, but no change.

Can anyone help me out here? I'm sure I'm missing something simple here, but I can't figure it out!

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `<div id="#testtest"` to `<div id="testtest"` 
`#` is just a key for jquery to search by ID

Comment: I don't believe I missed that! Ironically in my script from my previous question, that bit was fine, I just forgot to put it in a `$(document).ready` block which jsFiddle obviously doesn't require. In short... I had a stupid moment!

Answer (score 2):

Your DIV has ID of "#testtest" should be "testtest"